# Remove left and right side borders

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want my `TextBox` to look like this
[image]

How can I remove the left and right sides of my `TextBox` control?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: You'll probably have to override the paint method of the button

Comment: I saw some article but I am not able to understand their code. Some people are refering to paint the sides. How ca I pain the sides..

Comment: Have you tried making it look flat? Which is 3D by default.

Comment: Here's some info about the onpaint event you need to override http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx

Comment: @Yahya Flat style will just let you modify the whole border, not remove parts of it or do anything else

Comment: Anyone who suggests overriding the OnPaint of a textbox, please do a little research about TextBox in WinForms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd have to override the OnPaint event to do this, for a Textbox however, this will not work because OnPaint wont get called.

An approach would be to subclass TextBox as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/20/420551.aspx)

However I wouldnt suggest you to do this at all, it sounds like a daunting task to me (never did this myself), espacially when you are new to programming.

Maybe it would suffice to just draw a line above or beneath the TextBox?

**-edit-**

Maybe this will explain it better:

> The TextBox is special in that you can't custom paint it.
>   If you just want a custom border, you can create a new UserControl and add a TextBox with border style set to None. Make sure you leave enough room around the outside of the TextBox for a border. Then paint the border on the UserControl surface.
>   An alternative method would be to handle the WM_NCPAINT message of the TextBox and paint the border then, but that is significantly more complicated.

Source: shawn.ohern in msdn forums: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/986d375e-78bf-45ea-b53f-611a319b3af3/)
(Sorry I didnt know how to link to his post directly)

**-edit2-**
This [link](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/) shows a way to create your own TextBox, which, again, I would not recommend to someone who is new to c# and programming ;)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is based on Win32 API which, unlike WPF which uses declarative language for describing UI, gives you full control of painting your own control.

Take a look here: [Custom Control Painting and Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf.aspx).